# Can my script be edited to ignore invalid email recipients in Send.email?

Tags: google-apps-script

Im running a script to help a group keep track of translations. The goal is to have the translator notified (emailed) when a document is updated (each language has it's own sheet within the doc). Each recipients email is listed in it's own cell in the row of the document they are responsible for translating. The script will run occasionally, but I think it is getting caught up on cells that have text (not emails) listed where email addresses should be.

I keep getting the error: 'Failed to send email: no recipient (line 21, file "Translation Notification")'

Is there a way to update my script so that it will invalid email recipients?

```
 function shellFunction() {
  var sheets = ['Arabic', 'Portuguese', 'French','Spanish'];
  for (var s in sheets) {
    toTrigger(sheets[s]);
  }
}
  function toTrigger(sheetName) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
      var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
      var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
      var recipients = sheet.getRange('J' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();
      var message = '';
      if (cell.indexOf('B') != -1)     
      {
        message = sheet.getRange('A' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
      }
      var subject = 'The ' + sheet.getRange('F' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' ' + sheet.getRange('A' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' needs your Translation';
      var body = sheet.getRange('A' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' has been updated. Can you please update ' + sheet.getRange('G' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + '? Please remember to update the date column in the Resource Document when the translation is complete:' + ss.getUrl();
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
```

EDIT: I realized Im looking for the function to ignore all invalid emails (not just blank cells) and continue to run.

Comment: since you write "recipients" with an S, is there only one or possibly more than one recipients ? this could change the way to handle the error you get.  The answer below only handles the case of one recipient alone.

Comment: @Sergeinsas actually it handles one cell as indicated in var recipients =

Comment: Yes, one cell doesn't mean one email address... the recipient argument can be a string of comma separated emails, but thx for the information.

Comment: Correct. Just wanted to clarify that the answer below does in fact handle more than one recipient.

Comment: Except if some unpredictable data like a comma is present after an email... In that case the script would expect a second addressand wouldn't find it.

Comment: to be really sure you should check that the email is valid, that there are no spaces, no comma that could be misinterpreted.  The simplest solution would be to use a try/catch and trap the error this way.

Comment: Agreed. Try catch would be simplest way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
if (cell.indexOf('B') != -1)     
  {
  message = sheet.getRange('A' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'The ' + sheet.getRange('F' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' ' + sheet.getRange('A' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' needs your Translation';
  var body = sheet.getRange('A' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' has been updated. Can you please update ' + sheet.getRange('G' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + '? Please remember to update the date column in the Resource Document when the translation is complete:' + ss.getUrl();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
```

To:

```
if (cell.indexOf('B') != -1 && recipients != "")   
  {
  message = sheet.getRange('A' +  sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  var subject = 'The ' + sheet.getRange('F' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' ' + sheet.getRange('A' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' needs your Translation';
  var body = sheet.getRange('A' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' has been updated. Can you please update ' + sheet.getRange('G' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + '? Please remember to update the date column in the Resource Document when the translation is complete:' + ss.getUrl();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
```

**EDIT**

You can use any email regex that works best for you but something like this should work:

```
var recipients = sheet.getRange('J' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue().toString();

var getEmails = recipients.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
```

Now you have an array of hopefully valid emails that you can cycle through and use try/catch if there are still errors.

Note: no email regex is perfect

Comment: That's what I initially tried, but it still gives me the same error: 'Failed to send email: no recipient (line 23, file "Translation Notification")'  Any idea as to why the script thinks I have no recipient?

Comment: Can you use Logger.log to check the value of recipients to see if it actually is empty.  If we knew the value of recipients that is causing the error we could isolate the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
```

with:

```
// Just in case there is blank space in the cell, replace it.
recipients = recipients.replace(/\s/g, '');
// Ensure recipients is non-empty.
if (recipients) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: This works great with blank spaces, but not for typos. Is there a way to amend this so that it will ignore spaces and all invalid emails? (say someone has a typo in their email for example - I dont want the whole function to stop).

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can simply do a `try...catch`. So you would have

```
try {
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
}
catch(error) {
  Logger.log(error)
}
```

which should go through typos and empty rows. It will still try to send the message, so in terms of performance it's not great, but this should then continue on with the code despite the error (you can do something else with the `catch`, like add the row where the error occurred, or the address that is wrong to a string and later send the list to yourself or whoever should check the emails)

**EDIT: considering the comment left by asker to the answer.**

The other answers so far (including mine) are assuming that you have emails in separate cells and you would iterate over the emails, sending 1 to each. Please clarify your question as what you are looking to do is remove e-mails that have an invalid format from the string.

In that case your best bet (barring actualy email validation, which requires you to have a complete list of absolutely certainly correct emails) would probably be to check the string for format errors. Here is a sample that will remove any email that does not have the correct **format** (note email addresses that do not exist will still remain and whoever runs the script will recieve a response about a failed mail delivery):

```
function myFunction() {
  var recipients = 'email1@gmail.com,email2gmail.com,email3@gmail.com,email4@gmailcom'
  var arr = recipients.split(',')
  var arr2 = []
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i].indexOf('@') != -1){
      if (arr[i].indexOf('@') < arr[i].lastIndexOf('.')) {
        arr2.push(arr[i])
      }
    }
  }
  recipients = arr2.toString()
  return
}
```

Note, that you can refine the for loop a little to just use a single array instead of 2 by getting rid of the element inside the current array, however for simplicity sake and for it to be faster I wrote the easiest variant. In essence what this does is follows a simple logic:

1. Does the email have an `@` symbol? All emails must have one
2. Is there a `.` symbol **after** the `@` symbol. Again, this does not
   consider that the end might be `.co` or some other typo, only that
   it    exists. You could just check for a full blown `@gmail.com` or
   other    domain, if you are absolutely certain all emails will have
   that    domain.

Finally we combine the array back into the string (you can technically get away with just reusing the 1 `recipients` variable if you really want to). I personally think the code will look a bit messier if you do though.

Again, note that there are limitations here and you may need to add extra conditions. For example just off the top of my head I did not consider any checks for the following scenarios:

Email address does not have anythi

- ng after the last dot (e.g. `email@gmail.`)
- Email does not contain
  empty domain (`email@.` or `email@.com`) though I am unsure if gmail
  will fail on those

Comment: Recipients are in a cell and not rows so the above would have to be modified to continue after error.

Comment: @utphx please see the edited answer. Your question needs to be edited. The way it's written now, without a close read at your code or a comment like the one on this answer, it seems that the recipients are on separate cells (I believe the other answers work under the same assumption). My edited answer now includes how to handle a string of emails that are comma separated. Note that there are some limitations to this method, but you can customise the actual actions taken to do what you need. The logic remains similar

Comment: it's not my question. It seems clear to me that it's a cell not rows.

Comment: @utphx my bad. Without giving a close read on the code otherwise it's not specified. The question does lack that detail